# Override GSON parsing for one key

Tags: json, gson

Is it possible to override GSON parsing for only one key?

e.g.

```
Parse the following JSON:

{
  "a" : "data",
  "b" : "more data",
}
```

Into this class:

```
class Foo {

    String a;
    String b;

}
```

But transform "b" to uppercase during the deserialization process?

I'd like to avoid writing a custom deserializer and parsing all of the values manually as this is a big class.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `@JsonAdapter` annotation on a field to specify a specific typeadapter for that field. Then you only need to implement custom deserialization for that field

Comment: can you be more clear.. which `b` you are talking about java object `b` or json data `b`

Comment: Java object B. I'd like to take the data from the JSON file and transform it to uppercase in the Java object B.

Comment: check answer and let me know. is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

In Gson you can give multiple names for a key using [@SerializedName](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/index.html?com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) attribute

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1="{" +"  \"a\" : \"data\"," +"  \"B\" : \"more data\"}";
    String str2="{" +"  \"a\" : \"data\"," +"  \"b\" : \"more data\"}";

    Gson gson=new Gson();
    //result will be same for both str1 and str2
    Foo obj=gson.fromJson(str1, Foo.class);
    System.out.println(obj.getB());

}

class Foo {
    String a;
    @SerializedName(value="b", alternate={"B"})
    String b;

    //setter and getters
}
```